# I make a div (header_line) indent in margin using vw but when the distance of the scren decreases the entire content decreases very much and moves out

Tags: html, css

I make a div (header_line) indent in margin using vw but when the distance of the scren decreases the entire content decreases very much and moves out **Is it possible to fix it somehow?**
https://codepen.io/dxxdly/pen/jOxYzpP

```
<header class="header"> 
        <div class="header_line">
            <div class="logotip__nav">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="MetaRL">
                    </div>

                    <nav class="navigation">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Wave NFTs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Stories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
            </div>

        <div class="social">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/discord.png" alt="Discord"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/youtube.png" alt="Youtube"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/telegram.png" alt="Telegram"></a>
            </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: you set display to flex and wrap, so this is normal behavior. there is no problem. what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I mean, on a large monitor, if you scale the screen size, for example, not 100%, but 50%, everything moves to the center

Comment: yes, this is the flex display. could you please tell me what do you want to happen when decreasing or increasing screen size?

Comment: I want that on a large monitor there is no narrowing of the blocks to the center, and with a small one, on the contrary, everything is adaptive

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `flex-wrap:wrap` to your header_line element and and `media query`:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

                     transition:all 1s ease;

}

body {
/*  overflow-x: hidden;*/
    background-color: black;
}

header {
    max-width: 1440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
}

.header_line {
    margin: 0vw 7.29166666667vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.logotip__nav {
    display: flex;
}

.navigation > ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
}

.navigation > ul > li {
    padding-left: 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation > ul > li > a {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: DMMono;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.social > a > img {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 702px) {
.header_line{
  justify-content:center;
}
{
```

```html
<header class="header"> 
        <div class="header_line">
            <div class="logotip__nav">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="MetaRL">
                    </div>

                    <nav class="navigation">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Wave NFTs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Stories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
            </div>

        <div class="social">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/discord.png" alt="Discord"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/youtube.png" alt="Youtube"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/telegram.png" alt="Telegram"></a>
            </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, what you are talking about is called, responsive design. that means you will design layouts that display things properly in all screen sizes. so when you design it, you must consider all screen sizes, not just the one you are working on it. and that's what you did because you set `header max-width: 1440px;` and you also added two boxes on right and left by adding margin in header line. are you going to use them for logo or something?

Anyway, according to your comment, I edited the code to make header width 100%. I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I hope it is.

and to learn more about responsive layout, check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*    box-sizing: border-box; */
  /*   transition:all 1s ease; */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  /*    overflow-x: hidden;*/
  background-color: black;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.header_line {
  /*    margin: 0vw 7.29166666667vw; */
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logotip__nav {
  display: flex;
}

.navigation>ul {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}

.navigation>ul>li {
  padding-left: 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation>ul>li>a {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: DMMono;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.social>a>img {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header_line">
    <div class="logotip__nav">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="MetaRL">
      </div>

      <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Wave NFTs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Stories</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="social">
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/discord.png" alt="Discord"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/youtube.png" alt="Youtube"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/telegram.png" alt="Telegram"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: If what you mean is the movement when you load the page, then it's because of the transition. so just remove `transition: all 1s ease;` from your CSS.